# Can't retrieve my XML via crossdomain on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I've take this piece of code from W3C School which works perfectly on Ie and Chrome withtout change but when I change the 'url' parameter with my url it only works in Chrome and not in IE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("produits");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + "<tr>";
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("produit");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("nomprod");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";
      }
    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txtCDInfo">
<button onclick="loadXMLDoc('http://www.sosmalus.tm.fr/fexpat/webservices/choix_produits.php?dev_statut=1&dev_fdpaysid=AF&dev_fddeffet=2012-06-07&dev_fdnbadu=1&dev_fdnbenf=0&dev_fadnaiss_a_1=1952-06-19')">Get CD info</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea of what's wrong with that? Thanks!

**PS : I've added `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>` in the distant page**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IE supports CORS before IE10. The original code works for W3Schools probably because they are of the same origin.

Comment: ow :/ How can I fix that so 
? Is there an alternative solution?